# Factorization for $e^{\lambda x}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\lambda, x$ be real numbers. Why can't we factorize

$$e^{\lambda x}=f(\lambda)g(x)$$

for some functions $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we could. Then $1=e^0=e^{\lambda 0} = f(\lambda) g(0)$, so $f(\lambda)=\frac{1}{g(0)}$ is constant, but similarly we get $g(x)$ must also be constant, so $e^{\lambda x}$ would have to be constant for all $\lambda$ and $x$. But that's clearly nonsense.